# DropDownListFor and Multiple Select Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to generate a select tag with multiple options enabled, on the server side im generating a SelectListItem with NGO Objects, and a SelectedNGOes string array representing  the values that should be selected:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedNGOes,
                    new SelectList(Model.Ngoes, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "span6", multiple = "true"  })
```

Everything works well except the selected value are ignored during rendering, i made sure that the SelectedNGOes have the right values, not sure why the selections are being ignored.

Comment: Could you please share the logic in your controller, and perhaps part of your model indicating the object relationship.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownListFor sets the selected value to the value of the lambda and ignores the selected value in the select list.  set your lambda on the controller

```
Model.SelectedNGOes = "Selected Value";
```

and that value will be set on the view as long as it matches a value in the list